# Perl Dynamic Parameter to Function

Tags: arrays, perl, function, parameters

I've got one function which I can't modify and in this function something like this is done

```
 foreach my $param (@_) {
    .....
```

Now I want to call this function with dynamic parameters.
I've got an object which I get from

```
$self->{'parameter'} = from_json ( $self->{'cgi'}->param('POSTDATA') );
```

And now I want to do something like this

```
function(para1, $self->{'parameter'})
```

if I do it manually it works

```
function(para1, 1, 1, 1)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$self->{parameter}` is an array reference, then you can include the dereferenced array and in most<sup>*</sup> cases, Perl will flatten the list.

```
$self = from_json ...;                  # $self->{parameter} = [1,2,3];
function($p1,@{$self->{parameter}});    # equiv to function($p1,1,2,3)
```

<sup>*</sup> - some cases where Perl won't flatten a list are [functions that have a `@` prototype](https://metacpan.org/source/MUIR/List-EvenMore-0.11/lib/List/EvenMoreUtils.pm#L24) or a Perl [builtin function that expects an `ARRAY`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#push) and not just a `LIST`

Comment: Thank you! After the first test, it looks like it's going as you said

Comment: One Question. Is there a difference in writing $self->{'parameter'} and $self->{parameter} without ' ' ?

Comment: It's only a question of style.